# Register Service in ASP.NET Core as part of a middleware registration

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Using ASP.NET Core 3.1 I am adding a `SitemapMiddleware` on Startup's Configure method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder builder, IWebHostEnvironment environment) {
  builder.UseSitemap();
}
```

Where the `UseSitemap` extension is:

```
public static class SitemapMiddlewareExtensions {
  public static IApplicationBuilder UseSitemap(this IApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.MapWhen(x => x.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/sitemap.xml"), 
      x => x.UseMiddleware<SitemapMiddleware>(route));
  } 
}
```

But the middleware uses an `ISitemapService` which I need to register as:

```
services.AddScoped<ISitemapService, SitemapService>();
```

How can I do this inside the method `UseSitemap`?

Or maybe create an IServicesCollection extension to use in Startup's ConfigureServices that registers the SitemapService?

Comment: AFAIK, the moment we are talking of Middleware, we are essentially talking within the context of a specific request. We can keep adding services to our service collection as long as the ServiceProvider is not built. But the time we hit our middleware pipeline, we already have it built and we cannot register services anymore. Why is it you want to delay the registration of your dependency in this case?

Comment: `Or maybe create an IServicesCollection extension to use in Startup's ConfigureServices that registers the SitemapService?` YES, that is usually the recommended approach. By the time `Startup.Configure` is invoked, the service provider is already built and cannot be modified.

Comment: @Nikosi So I suppose I should have UseSitemap extension method in Configure to add the Sitemap middleware and AddSitemap extension in ConfigureServices to add the Sitemap service and other Sitemap configurations ... Does this make sense? I am just trying to create a Sitemap component to be used in different projects but that follows the guidelines of ASP.NET Core for registering and configuring the Middleware

Comment: @SaiGummaluri I have no need to delay the registration ... Maybe using UseSitemap extension method in Configure to add the Sitemap middleware and AddSitemap extension in ConfigureServices to add the Sitemap service and other Sitemap configurations ... Does this make sense? I am just trying to create a Sitemap component to be used in different projects but that follows the guidelines of ASP.NET Core for registering and configuring the Middleware

Comment: Hi. Just a friendly reminder. Still no accepted answer for this question. Do you need something else?